# classNotFoundException for testing a class in a different package of the same name

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

All of my test classes were working perfectly fine, then all of a sudden the following error happened. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes eclipse does this and if you force a clean and rebuild it fixes the problem.